# Is there a way to get the most recent line that has my search variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to parse a log file that shows ethernet statuses. It is updated everytime it is changed. I am parsing the log file by the port number, that port number is put into a list and then looped through taking each index and parsing the log file for a status. When I run it shows every instance of the port. I am trying to just get the most recent updated line. Any ideas?

```
f = open('file','r')
delim = "8110"
delim = "5126"
xgiglst = []
giglst = []
def portpars(*args, **kwargs):
    global f
    global giglst
    global xgiglst
    with f as f:
        for line in f:
            if delim1 in line and " " in line:
                xgig = line.split(" ")[4]
                xgig = xgig.split(":")[1]
                xgiglst.append(xgig)
            if delim2 in line and " " in line:
                gig = line.split(" ")[4]
                gig = gig.split(":")[1]
                giglst.append(gig)
        giglst = list(set(giglst))
        giglst.sort()
        print(xgiglst)
        print(giglst)

def levelpars(*args, **kwargs):
    global giglst
    global f
    global delim2
    for i in range(len(giglst)):
        search = "port:" + str(i)
```

Here is where I am stuck, I made another function that searches the file again for my specific port but it returns like 10 lines because the port was updated. Please ignore the prints, that is just for me to make sure I am getting the right returns.

Thanks,

Comment: some code will be helpful

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you're parsing by a port number, why put a this single number into a list and then loop through? There's only one anyway. And why are you looping through the file multiple times?

Comment: The port status changes, so, therefore, the status is updated in the log file. I need to make two lists one with port # and another with the status. The indexes have to match to make sure the correct port status match the port number. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Why all the global variables instead of using function parameters? And why do your functions take `*args` and `**kwargs` that they don't use?

Comment: Instead of appending to a list, just reassign a variable. At the end of the loop, the variable will contain the last value that was found in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of actually reopening and reading the log file, you can just `tail` the file. If you are not familiar with the Unix `tail` command, read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)). The `-f` flag is commonly used for file monitoring.

I am sure there are lots of implementations in Python.